# Principal Component Analysis to Time Series Data (PCA)

Tags: time-series, pca, stationarity, feature-scaling

What is the procedure to do PCA on time series data? I followed the following method and I want to know whether it is correct

1. Scaled the stationary time series
2. Did PCA on the series obtained by previous step.

Is scaling necessary when the series are stationary? I am using python to do the analysis.

Comment: How many dimensions does your original data have in addition to the time domain?

Comment: @Ceph I have 22 variables in my dataset in addition to time domain and all the variables are in their stationary form. Also, all the variables are log transformed.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you center your data when doing PCA, but you dont need to scale your data. We want the mean to be zero, but the variance doesnt have to be one. However, if you use a python library to do the PCA, chances are the package will do the centering for you. You should be extra careful with interpreting your output in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I used the sklearn.decomposition.PCA which can be found here [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) . The input data is centered but not scaled for each feature before applying the SVD. So shouldn't I scale my data? Scaling the training data doesn't provide good forecasts. Also why should I be extra careful when interpreting the output?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the variance is one but it matters a lot whether the different features have the same variance. Scaling is important to put all features on the same scale. Otherwise features that start out on larger scales are given preference by PCA.